# Material Preview displays black when using Attribute Node to set Base Color

Tags: rendering, shader-nodes

I'm trying to set the color of an object based on an attribute. I created the attribute "Col" for an object:

[image]

Then I used an Attribute Node to pass this value to the Base Color Input of the object's Principled BSDF:

[image]

Now what's really odd here to me is that while this has the proper effect on the color of the object in rendered mode:

[image]

It shows up black (no matter what I do, short of unplugging the Attribute node from the Principled BSDF's Base Color input) in Viewport Shading/Material Preview Mode:

[image]

Can't figure out what to do here. It would be really nice to view that attribute color in the material preview mode.

EDIT I got it working using Attribute(Color):

[image]

Still curious for a solution, if anyone has one.

Comment: are u in cycles?

Comment: Yeah, using cycles renderer.

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: Sure. I'm using Sverchok to do some stuff, just FYI: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PQgBEVgrEmVn2Eo3QhNQG5emNRXyrvW-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like the values you are passing for RGB are (0.06, 0.06, 0.06) which is quite towards the black (0. 0. 0) end of the spectrum. Is it possible the color is equally black in Cycles Rendered mode, but the object is being "brightened" by the World (Environment) Lighting?

Comment: No I don't think so. I adjusted it through its full range, no effect in material preview mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go in *Object Data* properties under *Color Attribute* clear the text box